# setting domain name in go daddy for a codeigniter project

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have completed my project in code igniter framework. And purchased a domain for the same from godaddy. My base url in config.php is

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') {

$ht = "https://";
} else {
$ht = "http://";
}
$config['base_url'] = $ht.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['base_url'] .= preg_replace('@/+$@','',dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])).'/';
```

But now when i type the url on browser am getting an index of page where two folders are displayed. cgi-bin and my project folder. When i click on my project folder my default controller is loaded. Instead of this i wish to redirect to my project folder directly as soon as i type the url in browser. Where should i change? In my code or in godaddy settings page? Anyone please help.

Comment: Move you all folders from the project folder to server home directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your project folder and copy all files and directory from it and past on root directory or "/"

and add a .htacess file and paste the following code to it.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

open your my project folder and copy all files and directory from it and past on root directory or "/"

it will workS

Comment: i have moved all my folders to public_html folder. Now my folder structure is  inside public html i have the folders like application, asset,system, index.php etc along with a cgi-bin folder. But now when i call the url say www.example.com it redirects to my default controller but shows a 404 error- page not found.

Comment: you need to define index function in your default controller